# Canonical curves are isomorphic if and only if they are projectively equivalent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to prove that two canonical curves are isomorphic if and only if they are projectively equivalent but I am not totally sure about my proof.

Let $C$ and $C'$ be two isomorphic canonical curves of genus $g$ and let $\phi\in PGL_g$. Then we have the following diagram commutes:
\begin{align*}
 \phi(C)\cong C'  &\overset{j}{\hookrightarrow} &\mathbb{P}^{g-1}\\
 \uparrow & & \uparrow\\
 C &\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow}  &\mathbb{P}^{g-1}
\end{align*}
where the vertical maps are both $\phi$
Now, the canonical sheaf is preserved:
\begin{align*}
   \omega_{C}
&=i^*\phi^*O(1)\\
&=(\phi\circ i)^*O(1)\\
&=(j\circ\phi)^*O(1)\\
&=\phi^* j^*O(1)\\
&=\phi^*\omega_{C'}
\end{align*}
and therefore the canonical curves are isomorphic.

Viceversa, if $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic, the projectivity can be made by sending the lines that cut the canonical sheaf on one curve to the line that cut the canonical sheaf of the other curve. Let $s_0,...,s_{g-1}$ be the generators for $\mathcal{L}(K)$, then the canonical embedding sends them to the projective coordinates $x_0$,...,$x_{g-1}$. Likewise, if $t_0$,...,$t_{g-1}$ span $\mathcal{L}(K)$ for $C'$ then the canonical embedding sends them to the projective coordinates of a second projective space, we call them $y_0$,...,$y_{g-1}$. Then the projectivity may be built by sending each $x_i$ to $y_i$.

Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

**Quesiton:** "I am trying to prove that two canonical curves are isomorphic if and only if they are projectively equivalent but I am not totally sure about my proof."

**Answer:** If $C$ is a non-hyperelliptic curve of genus $g\geq 3$, it follows the canonical divisor $K_C$ gives a closed immersion $C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{g-1}$. This immersion depends on a choice of basis of $H^0(C, \Omega^1_{C/k})$. Hence two such "canonical curves" $C,C'$ are isomorphic iff there is an automorphism $\phi$ of projective space with $\phi(C')=C$. Hence the "canonical curve" is defined up to such an automorphism.